# Subdividing executor services

Tags: java

I have an ExecutorService used for a specific purpose for child tasks. I feel it's more practical to use an ES for these, as each task should use one and only one of these threads. But I would like to enforce this at the service level. I am wondering if there's a way to subdivide or wrap an ExecutorService (ThreadPoolExecutor to be specific) such that I can pass the ES along, but limit the capabilities of it.

i.e. I want an ExecutorService set up for the set of system limitations. But I want to prevent any one task from consuming the entire ES (and / or have guaranteed minimum resources for all tasks).

Comment: Maybe you could have a specific `ExecutorService` for each service or groups of services? Otherwise you'd have to decorate a `ThreadPoolExecutor` and add the parititon logic you desire, taking care of concurrency.